# Is it okay to include PKs in json response during an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, python, django, postgresql

**Development Language:** Python

**Framework:** Django 1.11

**SQL:** PostgreSQL

I have this page that lists all job vacancies in a table. On each row, I have an `action link` at the end that opens a modal containing more information of the vacancy.

Data layout of the modal is already prepared, I just execute an `ajax call` so that the dynamic data gets updated with values related to the selected row i.e. *monthly salary, office designation, etc*.

Here is how my modal looks:

[image]

In my `views.py`, the way I throw the ajax response is by returning a `HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")` which results to having this as a json response:

[image]

The above response is via a `SELECT *` query. Some of those data are `primary key value` of referenced tables such as the `office` table.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good idea for me to return such json response?
2. Instead of using SELECT *, should I specify the fields I only need so I don't need to worry about those PK values being available for potential hacking?

Comment: You should always try and select only the columns you actually need. That is not even a question of security.

Comment: Yup that is what I thought too, I just needed some 'more experienced' geeks to validate that for me... and I've also updated this post's title... Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be using SELECT at all. You should be using Django's model layer; and then serialize the relevant fields from the queryset into the response.

Comment: Yes I am using the model layer for models created within my own app. However, this job_vacancy table exists on a separate database and is primarily maintained via a separate app, so I needed to use django.db.connections to be able to access that external db and perform raw SQL queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what other actions you are able to do in your website if a PK is known by a potential exploiter.  If they can only use it to construct URLs eg: `https://somedomain.com/job/1234/view` then it's clearly not an issue if the PK is returned.  However, if they can construct a payload to POST to a delete endpoint and you haven't got the correct cross origin and functional authorization in place, then it really will be a huge issue!

From a pure security view point, my starting position would always be to not return PKs unless you have a good reason and you know you have correct security in place everywhere it's needed (including access to your DB server).

Comment: Thanks a heap! You cleared things up for me... I've now decided to just pull the fields I only need as it's way better and safer.

Comment: I just have one more question though. Is it okay at all to return the response as json such as above? Because I've seen some other websites where their response is the entire modal (a markup) instead of json... this one for example, http://prntscr.com/p2jvv3

Comment: @Michael why should it be a problem to return the data as JSON? What concerns do you have about that? Anyhow you should not ask different further questions as comments.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure ;D Anway, thanks guys! Noted on the comments...